# Automated release to Azure web app using "AzureRM Web App Deployment" step

Tags: continuous-integration, release-management, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a build definition, which uploads artifacts (loads of css, js, aspx, dll files etc.) and is working as expected.

I now try to configure a release definition with the AzureRM Web App Deployment step to deploy this to a web app.

The web app already exists and I can deploy to it easily directly from Visual Studio.

In the step I have filled in the following fields:

- AzureRM Subscription (appears as expected in the dropdown)
- Web App Name (appears as expected in the dropdown)
- Package - I want to include all files, so I've set it to $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MyBuildDefinition/**/*.*
- SetParameter File - left blank

When I try to run the deployment the process finds the first file matching the flag and then fails with the following messages:

> 2016-08-31T16:01:37.7827094Z msdeploy.exe is located at 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe'
>
> 2016-08-31T16:01:37.7867084Z filePath = Find-Files -SearchPattern C:\a\r1\a/MyBuildDefinition/**/*.*
>
> 2016-08-31T16:01:38.3277086Z filePath = C:\a\r1\a\MyBuildDefinition\Web\App\app\build\css\brand-style.css
>
> 2016-08-31T16:01:38.5537092Z ##[error]Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'files'. Cannot convert value to type System.String.
>
> 2016-08-31T16:01:38.5907083Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy web app

I am using an OOTB hosted build server.

I also tried running this with Package field set to a zip file, which I created for testing, but this didn't work either.

How can I take advantage of this step in my scenario?

Can this consume non-zip files?, if it has to be zip then how do I generate it from my artifacts?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it.

It can't be just a normal zip file. It has to be a zip file generated using MSBuild.